# CodeIgniter - passing button value to form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code (view):

> ```
>       <?php echo $own['own'] ? form_open('games/updateOwn', 'id="ownGame"') : 
>              form_open('games/setOwn', 'id="ownGame"'); ?>
>             <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>">
>             <input type="hidden" name="gameid" value="<?php echo $game['id'];?>">
>             <button value="1" name="own[]">Mam/miałem</button>
>             <button value="2" name="own[]">Chcę mieć</button>
>             <button value="3" name="own[]">Nie interesuje mnie</button>
>         </form>
> ```

It is simple form for placing ownership in db. Model for that:

```
public function Own($data) {
        $gameid = $this->input->post('gameid');
        $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
        $own = $this->input->post('own');

        $this->db->cache_delete('games',$gameid);

        $ins_own = array(
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'game_id' => $gameid,
            'own' => $own
        );

        $q = $this->db->insert('ownership', $ins_own);
    }
```

And my problem is, `own` (`button`'s value) isn't submitted. How can I solve this?

Comment: I know, but mst of the time I can do this after two days. And I simply forgot about it ;) Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: on the html side own is an array, so on the server side try print_r($own) to see what it is and deal with it appropriately

Comment: It won't do, since Firebug shows that only `$gameid` and `$userid` are being submitted.

Comment: What do you see when you do **print_r($_REQUEST)**

Comment: @ParahatMelayev I got: `Array
(
    [userid] => 1
    [gameid] => 14
    [ci_session] => (...)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of workaround, and it isn't a good solution at all, but seems to work for now. It's biggest flaw is necessity of having enabled JavaScript. But nevertheless, here it is:

**View**

```
            <input type="hidden" name="own" value="" id="own">

            <button value="1"<?php echo $own['own'] == '1' ? ' class="selected"' : ''; ?>>Mam/miałem</button>
            <button value="2"<?php echo $own['own'] == '2' ? ' class="selected"' : ''; ?>>Chcę mieć</button>
            <button value="3"<?php echo $own['own'] == '3' ? ' class="selected"' : ''; ?>>Nie interesuje mnie</button>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
    $('form#ownGame button').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('#own').val(val);
            return false;
        })
    })
```

I hope it may help someone. But I'm **still open for any of your new propositions or answers!**

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` will have a type of button by default so you should add `type="submit"` to each one to make this work.

```
<button type="submit" value="1" name="own">Mam/miałem</button>
<button type="submit" value="2" name="own">Chcę mieć</button>
<button type="submit" value="3" name="own">Nie interesuje mnie</button>
```

Comment: also remove the `[]` or own will be an array, you can only click 1 button its not a checkbox!